# How to ignore apostrophe in url via .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using following rule in my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]*)/(.*)/t/(([\d]|[\-])+)$ pronew/ci/touch.php/touch/TouchSearchController?fl-brand=$2&category=$3 [L,QSA]
```

So when I access http://local.xyz.com/personal-care-men's-toiletries/t/12345 url, it gives me.

```
Array
(
    [fl-brand] => ci/index.php/personal-care-men's-toiletries
    [category] => 12345
)
```

In $_GET but if I remove the single quote from the url I do not get fl-brand param in $_GET which is correct behavior.

How Can I ignore single quotes in the url so that I get only

```
Array
(
    [category] => 12345
)
```

Comment: `\w` is "alphanumeric characters", which DOESN'T include `'`. You'd have to use `[\w\-']` instead. Note the extra escape to prevent the `-` from being seen as a range operator.

Comment: It seems you have 4 segments: `[\w-]*`, `.*`, `t`, and `([\d]|[\-])+` (which could be simplified as `[\d-]+`). But your URL only has 3: `personal-care-men's-toiletries`, `t`, and `12345`.

Comment: @MarcB or you can include the `-` at the beginning or end of the character class: `[\w'-]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this negation based regex for first part and use `\d+` for last part:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/t/([0-9]+)/?$ pronew/ci/touch.php/touch/TouchSearchController?fl-brand=$1&category=$2 [L,QSA]
```